# Issues with having variables in the prepare part of a prepared statement

Tags: php, mysqli, prepared-statement

I'm trying to do an update query. The part that is throwing me off is having the variables in the prepare part of this. I'm trying to grab the existing $cid and $tid that is associated with the page I am on.

```
$cid = category id
$tid= topic id
```

I commented out the bind paramater because I already have the variables defined on the page.

I then get this error:

```
Fatal error: Call to a member function execute() on a non-object in
```

How can I make this prepared statement work and make this an object so it runs?

```
$stmt3 = $con->prepare("UPDATE forum_topics SET topic_views='".$new_views."' WHERE category_id'".$cid."' AND id='".$tid."' LIMIT 1");
//$stmt3->bind_param("ii", $cid, $tid);
$stmt3->execute();
$stmt3->store_result();
$row3 = $stmt3->fetch();
    }   else {
```

Additional code...

```
$old_views = $row['topic_views'];
$new_views = $old_views + 1;

        //$stmt3 = $con->prepare("UPDATE forum_topics SET topic_views='".$new_views."' WHERE category_id'".$cid."' AND id='".$tid."' LIMIT 1");
            $stmt3 = $con->prepare("UPDATE forum_topics SET `topic_views`=? WHERE `category_id`=? AND `id`=? LIMIT 1");
        $stmt3->bind_param("iii", $new_views, $cid, $tid);
            $stmt3->execute();
            //$stmt3->store_result();
            $row3 = $stmt3->fetch();
    }   else {
        echo "<p>This topic does not exist.</p>";
        }
```

Comment: I actually just got that working today. I had to rewrite it a bunch of times. This is expanding on that same page, just trying to figure out this part so it will work.

Comment: I did this and got it to work... `$stmt3 = $con->prepare("UPDATE forum_topics SET topic_views='".$new_views."' WHERE `category_id`=? AND `id`=? LIMIT 1");
   $stmt3->bind_param("ii", $cid, $tid);
    $stmt3->execute();`

Comment: Actually the $new_views part isn't working.

Comment: thats great, i have your database snapshot and `id` col is auto increment so adding id in it is not good approach

Comment: this is what makes up new_views... `$old_views = $row['topic_views'];
   $new_views = $old_views + 1;` My page view will go from 0 to 1, but then if I look at the post again it stays at 1. Any idea?

Comment: I added in more code to help. I just don't get why it adds the first view but then doesn't add anymore.

Comment: echo `$new_views` before `UPDATE` and lets say if I view a page it marks it 1 view and it only marks it view 2 unless i reopen the page again

Comment: It echos out 1. If I leave the page and come back it will still say 1, or if I x out my site and come back and do it all again it still says 1.

Comment: query won't just execute by itself or opening the page, you need to tell it to execute, by just opening page nothing will happen

Comment: Aren't I doing that with `$stmt3->execute();`? The page view count is on the page before this page.

Comment: or may be `UPDATE` query not executing first place at all so you are getting 1 becoz $new_views = $old_views + 1; `$old_views=0`

Comment: It has to be working, at least somewhat -Not sure if it can only partially work??- But it is updating into my db as 1 in the appropriate place, it just doesn't continually add 1 per view.